# Adding 'row adding behavior to webdatagrid programatically

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

Can anyone help me adding row adding behavior to webdatagrid programmatically:

```
Dim RowAdditions As RowAdding =   
webDataGrid1.Behaviors.EditingCore.Behaviors.CreateBehavior(Of RowAdding)()
```

This is giving me the object null exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up   http://forums.infragistics.com/forums/p/46977/251874.aspx#251874

Comment: how did u achieve this ? Please let me know, I am stuck in this since long